# can I integrate my speech to text translator application in Microsoft teams?

Tags: azure, artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I am developing a web application speech to text translator using [Azure Cognitive Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/).

Now I want to integrate my web application with Microsoft Teams or any similar Meeting platform that can work in real time.

Are there any sources?

Answer (score 0):

Transcription is already in Teams.

Live caption is a feature that you can turn on from Teams by  More options  > Turn on live captions (preview)..

This is only for scheduled meetings.

Translation is coming to Teams soon.

Comment: Hi Lisa, I agree transcription is already in Teams but say if we want custom language (ex: Malayalam) to be integrated, is there any facility in Teams ? or, do you have any idea how can we integrate our own speech-to-text plugin ?